# Do javascript closures with a this/self reference cause memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, events, memory-leaks, this

From what I understand about memory leaks, referencing an out-of-scope var within a closure will cause a memory leak.

But it is also a common practice to create a "that" var in order to preserve the "this" reference and use it within a closure, especially for events.

So, what's the deal with doing stuff like this:

```
SomeObject.prototype.createImage = function(){
    var that = this,
        someImage = new Image();
    someImage.src = 'someImage.png';
    someImage.onload = function(){
        that.callbackImage(this);
    }
};
```

Wouldn't that add a little leakage to a project?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, yes it does cause memory leaks, at least in some browsers (guess which).  This is one of the more compelling reasons to put your trust in one of the various frameworks available and to set up all your event handlers via its mechanisms instead of directly adding "DOM 0" event handlers like that.

Internet Explorer (at least prior to 9, and possibly including 9) has two memory allocation mechanisms (at least) internally: one for the DOM, and one for JavaScript (well JScript).  They don't understand each other. Thus even if a DOM node is freed up, any closure memory as in your example will not be freed.

*edit* — Oh, and the reason I mention frameworks is that they generally include code to try and mitigate this problem. The avoidance of attaching anything to DOM node properties is one of the safest approaches. All browsers worth worrying about (including ancient IE versions) have alternative ways of attaching event handlers to DOM nodes, for example.

Comment: The statement `The avoidance of attaching anything to DOM node properties is one of the safest approaches` can't go unchallenged. Accessing element properties directly is by far the fastest, easiest, most intuitive and robust (i.e. works in all browsers)
 method for assigning or reading values of DOM element properties. While there may be a number of ways to create memory leaks, placing a blanket ban on accessing element properties is not good adivce and will not necessarily avoid them.

Comment: *Accessing* element properties is fine; it's hanging JavaScript data structures off of elements that's a problem. jQuery, for example, assiduously avoids that. (Notice that I explicitly wrote **attaching**.)

Comment: Ok, the "data structures" part makes sense. Wherever possible, listeners should be a function reference or simple call, which will avoid issues with closures and circular references and therefore also memory leaks.

Comment: @RobG Yes that's true, but even a function reference can be a problem if the function has a closure around it. That's why it's so much better to use "attachEvent"/"addEventListener" to associate handlers with elements.

Comment: Oh, and using a library will not help, you can still create circular references and hence potential leaks using attachEvent and addEventListener. Libraries mostly try to avoid leaks by removing all listeners on unload, but that is a pretty simple strategy to implement in your own library.

Comment: Are you sure of that?  Generally the JavaScript runtime systems are able to deal with the garbage collection problems of their own allocations. The real IE problem comes from the mix of DOM and JScript memory.  JavaScript memory managers are generally not simple reference count systems; they're more like "mark and sweep" collectors, and those don't have problems with circular references.

Comment: I know for certain that the big memory leak in early IE 6 was from [circular references involving DOM elements](http://getben.com/archive/2006/05/30/Resolving-JavaScript-Memory-Leaks.aspx). My answer below shows how to create a circular reference using *attachEvent*, you can do exactly the same with *addEventListener*.

Answer (score 1):

There was a time with IE that circular references involving DOM elements (which were typically formed by closures when assigning a function to a listener) caused memory leaks, e.g.

```
function foo() {
  var someEl = document.getElementById('...');
  someEl.onclick = function() {...};
}
```

However, I think they are fixed or patched sufficiently that unless testing shows otherwise, they can be ignored. There are also a number of ways to avoid such closures, so even if they are an issue, they can be worked around (e.g. don't create circular references involving DOM elements).

#### Edit

Using libraries or any other method of attaching listeners can still create circular references and memory leaks, e.g. in IE:

```
function foo() {
  var el = document.getElementById('d0');

  // Create circular reference through closure to el
  el.attachEvent('onclick', function(){bar(el);});

}

function bar(o) {
  alert(o == window.event.srcElement);  // true
}

window.onload = foo;
```

The above uses *attachEvent* to add a listener (which pretty much **all** frameworks will use for IE < 9, including jQuery) yet still creates a circular reference involving a DOM element and so will leak in certain versions of IE. So just using a library **will not fix the issue**, you need to understand the causes and avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark here, but I reckon that:

```
someImage.onload = function(){
    that.callbackImage(this);
    someImage.onload = null
}
```

would clean up the "memory leak" left by `that`

Comment: Only if the listener is called (which it should be, but it may not).